# How to change grails default renderer

Tags: grails, view, action

I am using grails only to develop backed services and UI is done in angularJS or other technologies. Basically it means I am not writing any "view"s.
I am not overriding any CRUD methods in controller.

My controller looks like this:

```
class EmployeeController extends RestfulController {
    EmployeeController() {
        super(Employee)
    }
}
```

So this being the case, when an GET request is made from **browser** grails responds like this:
HTTP Status 404 - /file-tracker/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/employee/show.jsp

I guess grails by default renders views. 
But when the same GET request is made from **curl**, I get the data.

What is wrong ? Should I have to override 'show' action and render JSON explicitly (as I require JSON data in response) ?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of [content negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#contentNegotiation). The clue is the `Accept` HTTP header, which is sent by browser and is not sent by `curl` if you haven't explicitly defined it.

Have a look at [RestfulController](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy?source=c) source code and the definition of [respond](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/respond.html) method.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander , you mean the Accept is not sent by browser by default. Because, I am sending Accept from curl.

Comment: No, every browser sends Accept header. For example, my Chrome sends `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`

Comment: oh...I am not sure what is the problem ? grails doing something with the Accept header ?


from curl, with Accept header -- it works

from curl, without Accept header -- 404

from browser (I assume browser is setting Accept) -- 404

from angularJS application with/without Accept -- 404

Comment: same as above comment, just proper formatting:

oh...I am not sure what is the problem ? grails doing something with the Accept header ? 
from curl, with Accept header -- it works,
from curl, without Accept header -- 404,
from browser (I assume browser is setting Accept) -- 404,
from angularJS application with/without Accept -- 404

Comment: Yes, Grails deals with `Accept` header. It's described at the link about content negotiation I've provided. Also, it'll be helpful to investigate the source code of RestfulController after studying about content negotiation.